# php variable include error global

Tags: php, jquery, html, refresh, undefined

My main PHP page, is a 1 text-box form. The form is submitted to itself and displays the info (machine.php?pc=workstation101) pulled from a DB.

Also on this page I have a separate ping.php include that will ping the searched machine every 60 seconds. This is placed in a div and jQuery auto refreshes this external ping.php page.

If I disable the jQuery refresh code (shown below) ...

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#pinger").load("inc/ping.php");
      var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#pinger").load('inc/ping.php');
      }, 60000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  });
</script>
```

...the include file works fine. Shows the correct ping status. I do have to use $GLOBALS['variable'] to access variables from the parent index.php page however. But it works fine when I do .

Now after if I enable the refresh jQuery I get a ton of "Notice: Undefined index:...." errors. I have narrowed it all down to the $_GET['pc'] not being passed in any form of the sense when its reloading the DIV contents.

It works as a include. Fails as a jQuery load page. Perhaps I could code the include page into the index page and refresh the div contents without an external page? Cannot seem to find code that would work with that method.

Ideas?

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question. You are not passing `pc` in your query string with your jquery code. Your php is expecting to find it. Notices are thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including a PHP page and fetching it from the browser are two completely different things.

When you tell jQuery to load inc/ping.php, it is exactly as though you loaded that page in another browser window. The original PHP page has finished already, and its variables no longer exist.

In this case, you just need to construct a URL like /dynamic/ping.php?pc=foo and load that.

Comment: Good pointer, thank you. Fixed the two line in my JS....

$("#pinger").load("inc/ping.php?pc=<?php echo $machinename ?>");

Answer (score 0):

i'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve and I can't comment to ask but that jquery doesn't look right. First of all im assuming that you want to pass the value of your textbox to a PHP backend?

Try this in the script:

```
<script>
    function ping(){
        $.ajax("inc/ping.php?pc="+encodeURIComponent($("#your_textbox_id").val()),{})
            .success(function(data)){
                // Your php return values are here
            }).fail(function(error){
                // alert('somthing went wrong');
            })
        });
        window.setTimeout("ping()", 60000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        ping();
    });
</script>
```

Note that this is untested and may have syntax errors... but might solve your problem